# How to refresh MainActivity after using SettingActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, setting

following situation:
I have a MainActivity with some simple UI widgets (Buttons, TextView, EditTexts)
and I have a SettingActivity with atm 2 options.

So my problem ist, if I change something in the settings, it should be applied to the MainActivity.
currently I have a refresh Button which is rather not practically.

I tried different solutions, for example onPause() and onResume() which haven't worked.

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Start `SettingActivity` using `startActivityForResult` from `MainActivity` then use `setResult` method for passing data which you want to update in `MainActivity`.

In MainActivity override `onActivityResult` method of Activity which called when can back from `SettingActivity`. then in `onActivityResult` method you can refresh UI according to  results from SettingActivity. See this example for starting activity to get result back :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use sharedpreferences. The default android setting activity  will store all your setting option state in defaultsharePreferences so just read sharedPreferences the on your activity  onResume callback  method and do the logic accordingly.

Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: But how should I use it?
Where and when am I supposed to call onPause() and onResume()?

Comment: OnResume()  you should always  call that if you want to refresh UI